# Approach to table columns (custom, resize, reorder, sort, filter) w quick search

Tags: datatables

I'm a single indie novice web-developer (no money, no help, no education, no expirience) working on an extensive personal project with lots and lots of data. Started learning HTML, CSS, JS, jQuery, PHP, MySQL five months ago. Now I need to begin development of the part of the UI which should provide user with data tables. And I really think the next functionality is crucial:

- columns should be sortable (ascending-descending) by clicking on them
- columns should be resizable
- user need to be able to drag&drop columns to reorder them
- user need to be able to filter table by quick search through all columns
- user need to be able to filter table independently column by column
- user need to be able to select custom columns to show/hide
- user need to be able to save/load views (presets of table configuration - column selection, sorting, filters)

I know, that's a lot. And I know that's probably not easy. But surely there is no need for me to invent a bicycle from the ground up. I hope there are some solutions already implemented. I heard of DataTables plugin for jQuery. But I'm not sure, it seems it provides only some of features I need. And I don't know if other are compatible or better, or even exist. So I humbly ask for recommendations considering direction and approach I should take. It's ok if I'll need months to implement everything I need (time I do have). But I'd like to be sure I'm going the right way, and the final result will be usable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use datatable..
attach by default :(use jquery and bootstrap cdn )
attach datatables css and js cdn .. 
create a table tag and give tableid ..

$('#tableid').DataTable( {
       dom: 'Bfrtip',
        buttons: [
            'copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'pdf', 'print'
        ],

    responsive: true,
    scrollX:true,
    scrollY:true,


} );

place this script...thats it...table with filter entries,pagination ,responsive,scrolling,exporting to excel ,pdf will work now...there are more functions too..go to datatable website and practice examples...table simplified....

maximum it takes  half an hour to complete  including date range filter....

plese refer webslesson tutorials on youtube...nearly 240 mini projects are there for web developers ...you will be an expert within a month..all d best